# How to get Mat field from Mat row

Tags: angular

I am showing grid using Material Table(Angular 7). 
One of the column is editable(Datefield), and it can also be reset.
I am having trouble understanding to how to read the Matfield on a selected row. (How to get Mat field which is inside Mat Row (Mat Table)).
[image]

Comment: you could use a template ref, or [viewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

Comment: Thanks. Looking  into it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `[(ngModel)]` attribute on the input field associated with your datepicker.

I've drawn up a stack blitz which you should be able to see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rt88hl

If you click the click me button without modifying any data you should see the default data included in `app.component.ts`

If you change something and then see the update information you should see the date. Basically all the information is always inside the component's `tableSource` variable in this case.

Example Output:

[image]